# Finding one or more strings of a certain kind in a list of tuples

Tags: python, nltk

Let's say I have the following tuples:

```
tagged = [('They', 'PRP'),
 ('refuse', 'VBP'),
 ('to', 'TO'),
 ('permit', 'VB'),
 ('us', 'PRP'),
 ('to', 'TO'),
 ('obtain', 'VB'),
 ('the', 'DT'),
 ('refuse', 'NN'),
 ('permit', 'NN')]
```

I want to take all combinations of one or more nouns (that are in a sequence). Therefore, the output would be:

```
['refuse','permit','refuse permit']
```

I'm able to get the first two like this:

```
filtered = [x[0] for x in tagged if x[1]=='NN']
```

But I'm currently unable to find a way to get sequences of `'NN'` in the list.

EDIT:

This list is a better example:

```
 [('If', 'IN'),
 ('the', 'DT'),
 ('company', 'NN'),
 ('name', 'NN'),
 ('or', 'CC'),
 ('job', 'NN'),
 ('title', 'NN'),
 ('includes', 'VBZ'),
 ('multiple', 'JJ'),
 ('words', 'NNS'),
 (',', ','),
 ('use', 'NN'),
 ('double', 'JJ'),
 ('quotation', 'NN'),
 ('marks', 'NNS'),
 ('.', '.')]
```

Should  return:

```
['company', 'name', 'company name', 'job', 'title', 'job title', 'use', 'quotation']
```

Comment: Have you looked into `itertools.groupby`? This could easily get you groups of the same tag.

Comment: what about adding this line: filtered.append(" ".join(filtered))

Comment: @YOBA That works for this example but not if I have other 'NN' in the list that are not in a sequence of 'NN'.

Comment: Please stop approving pointless minor edits, it only encourages more of them to end up in the review queue.

Comment: @jonrsharpe itertools.groupby does not solve the problem of sequenced 'NN'

Comment: @GonçaloCorreia ...doesn't it? It can get you groups of adjacent words with the same tag, which seems to be what you're asking about, then you can iterate over the groups and easily check the tag the whole group shares. And why do you expect the first appearances of `'refuse'` and `'permit'` in your output, given that they *aren't* nouns there?

Comment: Maybe it was a bad example. What I really want is elements that are 'NN' and also sequences of elements that are 'NN'. Maybe the edit I just did makes things clearer?

Comment: Yes, that's fine, and it's still clear that `itertools.groupby` *would* help you do this (I've just tested as much locally).

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to do this with `groupby`?

Comment: You're not going to give it a try yourself, first?

Comment: Before posting the question I was playing around with `groupby` but didn't really get the sequence part...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty simple `groupby` operation with a little processing.  If we group by the tags and only look at the groups of nouns then we're almost there.  The only thing to be done then is join the groups that have more than 1 item and put the stuff in the output in the proper order:

```
from itertools import groupby

def group_nouns(iterable):
    for key, group in groupby(iterable, key=lambda t: t[1]):
        if key == 'NN':  # only worry about groups of nouns.
            seq = [t[0] for t in group]  # drop tags.
            if len(seq) == 1:
                yield seq[0]
            else:
                for noun in seq:
                    yield noun
                yield ' '.join(seq)
```

Comment: `' '.join(seq)` will work even where `len(seq) == 1`, FWIW

Comment: @jonrsharpe -- Yes, but it seems that OP doesn't want to put the 1-element sequences in the output twice so I think that case still needs to be special cased.  (e.g. `['company', 'name'] -> `['company', 'name', 'company_name'] but `['use']`  -> `['use']`)

Comment: Oh, I see. Their output is a bit weird!